# ACTIVITY screen in my profile needs work

Tags: support

As usual, change provokes more change... the new ACTIVITY screen needs some tweaking...

BADGES shows up twice...

[image]

[image]

And REPUTATION should be moved up IN PLACE of the first BADGES image...

[image]

Comment: I suggest you to post this as an answer here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/372049

Comment: @RandomPerson Thanks for the suggestion. However, I followed that link, and what a disaster that question has become. TLDR.

Comment: Wow ... -244. That MSE question is perhaps the most hated item on any SE page 

Comment: This is not related to Ask Ubuntu because there is nothing anyone here can do other than commiserate in their beers with you.

Comment: @matigo There have been other cases too... like this: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/333089